# Background subtraction using median in time

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, median, background-subtraction

I need to perform background subtraction in matlab.
I have a short video of a man crossing over a wall from right to left, so it is a simple and quite stable video.

I learned about a method to estimate the background using median in time: we need to take some window of frames (let's say - 25 frames), and perform a median **over time** so we can get the "median image" which should be a good estimation for the BG (in that kind of video, for a large enough window, the presence of the moving object should be negligible with regards to the BG for a BG pixel). once we have the BG estimation we\ll be able to subtract it from a frame, etc.

My questions are:

1. If my video is an RGB video - how do I perform the median operation? I tried using the Hue channel of each frame, but it doesn't work (see my code below).
2. basically - what's the simplest way to do it? I'm not sure about the quality of my implementation and would like to get some advise... thanks

**EDIT**: the video I'm using is pretty similar to the ones that can be found [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SpaceTimeActions.html) under "Classification database" --> "walk".

---

```
K = 31; % window size
half_win = (K+1)/2;
thresh = 0.7; % threshold for the subtraction

reader = VideoReader('input.avi');
writer  = VideoWriter('bianry.avi');
open(writer);

window = cell(1,K);
% handling first frame
[h,~,~] = rgb2hsv(im2single(readFrame(reader)));
window{half_win} = h;
k = 1;
% mirror padding of frames
while hasFrame(reader)
    if k == half_win
        break
    end
    [h,~,~] = rgb2hsv(im2single(readFrame(reader)));
    window{half_win + k} = h;
    window{half_win - k} = h;
    k = k + 1;
end
n = ndims(window{1});
bg = median(cat(n+1, window{:}), n+1);
fg = abs( window{half_win} - bg ) > thresh;
writeVideo(writer, im2uint8(fg));

while hasFrame(reader)
     [h,~,~] = rgb2hsv(im2single(readFrame(reader)));
    % update window
    window(1:K-1) = window(2:K);
    window{K} = h;
    bg = median(cat(n+1, window{:}), n+1);
    fg = abs( window{half_win} - bg ) > thresh;
    writeVideo(writer, im2uint8(fg));
end

% mirror padding for the end of the video
ind = K-1;
for k=1:(half_win - 1)
    frame_to_mirror = window{ind};
    window(1:K-1) = window(2:K);
    window{K} = frame_to_mirror;

    bg = median(cat(n+1, window{:}), n+1);
    fg = abs( window{half_win} - bg ) > thresh;
    writeVideo(writer, im2uint8(fg));
    ind = ind -2;
end

close(writer);
```

Comment: Why do you want to determine the background using a color image? You can convert it to grayscale first. You can also try to take the median of each RGB channel separately. An example video may be useful (you can just post a link to it in your question).

Comment: It is an exercise I got - we need to take a video similar to the one I described - first we need to stabilize it, then we need to put the walking person on a different background (of our choice; i.e to perform matting), and then to track this person (on the new background).

Comment: I added a link to some similar video exmaples @m7913d

Comment: Based on your task description, it seems to me that you may perform the background detection using a grayscale version of your video.